# SetPositions stop Audio and Video not simulaneously

Tags: delphi, directshow, dspack

I'm using DirectShow via Delphis'w wrapper called DsPack. I want to play some video from StartPosition till EndPosition:

```
MediaSeeking.SetPositions(Start, AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning, 
    Stop, AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning);
```

It works except the weird effect: video stops in a seconds or two after video. First I thought something is wrong with codecs... but if I pause/stop video manually, there is no such an effect. So am I using SetPositions wrong?

**Update.** Here is the file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/957029/Stuff/0.avi Checked on other files - this behaviour is not reproduced.

Comment: The actual behavior depends on specific filter support for `IMediaSeeking`, this is why you are seeing the problem on some files but not the other.

Comment: Check if there any anomalies in [seeking caps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373501) for that file. Sorry, I'm way too lazy this weekend.

Comment: There are two [duplicate] audio streams in that file. Not sure if that makes a difference?